# Re-run function if false

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I'm working on code that takes a random value, checks if it's correct with a few checks and if it is, it'll return it. If it isn't, it's supposed to rerun the function untill one that does is found.

If the random value is correct it'll set a var to 1 like this: `$chosen = 1;` and then using a while loop it'll keep running the current function untill it's 0:

```
public function generate_chair($id, $optredenID)
{
    $model = new Model_Shop;

    // Get all the chairs for the given room
    $chairs = $model->check_chair($id);

    // Get an array of reserved chairs for a given event
    $reserved = $model->get_reserved($optredenID);

    do {
        // If chosen = 0, all chairs are available.
        // If chosen = 1, one of the chairs is not available
        $chosen = 0;

        // Create a new empty array
        $rand_chairs = array();

        // Pick a random chair
        $chair = array_rand($chairs);

        // Based off the amount chosen in the dorpdown, build array
        switch($_POST['AantalPlaatsen']) {
            case '1':
                array_push($rand_chairs, $chair);
            break;

            case '2':
                array_push($rand_chairs, $chair);
                array_push($rand_chairs, $chair+1);
                // Check if the chair chosen is the last chair in a row
                // If it is, check for another chair
                if($chair == 20 || $chair == 40 || $chair == 60 || $chair == 80 || $chair == 100 || $chair == 120 || $chair == 140 ||$chair == 160 ||  
                $chair == 180 || $chair == 200) {
                    $chosen = 1;
                }
            break;

            case '3':
                array_push($rand_chairs, $chair);
                array_push($rand_chairs, $chair+1);
                array_push($rand_chairs, $chair+2);
            break;

            case '4':
                array_push($rand_chairs, $chair);
                array_push($rand_chairs, $chair+1);
                array_push($rand_chairs, $chair+2);
                array_push($rand_chairs, $chair+3);
            break;
        }

        // Check if one of the random generated chairs is in the reserved array
        // If so, the chair is unavailable and new random must be generated
        if( count(array_intersect( $rand_chairs, $reserved )) != 0 ) {
            $chosen = 1;
        }

    } while ($chosen == 1);

    return $rand_chairs;
```

What I wanted works now, but I'm wondering if anyone has a idea for another issue.
As shown in the switch-case, when the customer chooses 2 chairs and the first one is at the end of a row, it has to check for a new chair, because you can't spread multiple chairs over multiple rows.

The way I do this is with alot (too many) if statements. Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: use while to loop until chosen is 0.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you included a bit more of your code. As it stands now, the question seems too vague to me. You could answer it in a dozen different ways.

Comment: @kuroineko I've updated the post to include the entire function.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a random place where you can have n seats together. It would be more efficient to find all the places in your array where there are blocks of empty seats, then pick one of these blocks randomly. This algorithm will get very slow when the theatre starts to fill up...

Comment: Floris makes a good point; I wrote an answer to your question, but you should consider a different algorithm.

Comment: @Floris I'd love to make faster code, but I have no idea how I would look for places in the array where there are enough empty spaces in a row

Comment: @Lokno I've updated my post to include your suggestion. But when I run it, it sometimes still loads a very long time and then returns me an error saying "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded".

Comment: @user1422479 Sorry, I made a mistake. `$chosen` needs to be reset at the beginning of the do-while loop, otherwise it will never terminate. Just move the `$chosen` initialization into the do-while block and you can safely remove the break statement. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Lokno Thanks, this works perfectly :). There is 1 more thing that I can solve myself but I wonder if you have a better solution. I can't have 4 chairs spread over 2 rows (all chairs gotta be on the same row). A row has 20 chairs, so I could do if($chair == 20) {$chosen = 1} when the chairs wanted = 2 or higher, but this results in ALOT of if statements (especially since I have rooms with up to 500 chairs). Would you know a way to check for this? I'll update my code with an example of what I have.

Comment: @user1422479 Assuming 1-indexing, as your code implies (i.e., $chair is in the range 1 to n): `if( $chair % $rowLength == 0 ) $chosen = 1;` Where `$rowLength = 20;`

Comment: @Lokno Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try this tomorrow (today) as it is 0:30 here. You've already been a great help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using recursion here? Why not just repeat the part of the function which you need to rerun?

```
do {
    $chosen = 0;

    // create a new empty array
    $rand_chairs = array(); 

    // Pick a random chair
    $chair = array_rand($chairs);

    ...

    foreach($rand_chairs as $key) {
        if(in_array($key, $reserved)) {
            $chosen = 1;
            break; // oops, we need to rerun
        }
    }
} while( $chosen == 1 )
```

This uses a `do-while` control structure, which runs through the body at least once.
The `break` statement exits out of the while loop early, since the key has been found.

Additionally, instead of the `foreach` statement, you could use `array_intersect()`:

```
if( count(array_intersect( $rand_chairs, $reserved )) != 0 ) {
    $chosen = 1;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but after a few times instead of an array it just loads for a while and then returns an empty screen. This seems to only happen when $chosen == 1.

Comment: I've updated my post to include more code. I think the actual problem might be with setting the $chosen var since it either shows the array or loads for a long time.

Comment: I edited my post based on your changes. I should have asked for more information before. I think you're misusing recursion here.

Answer (score 0):

Faster algorithm would go something like this: you would run it one row of seats at a time, since "sitting at opposite ends of adjacent rows" isn't really "sitting together"...

```
Boolean seatsTaken()
int startsAt(), runLength()
For each row in seatsTaken
  adjacent = 0
  seat = 0
  while not row(seat):
    ++adjacent
  if adjacent > 0:
    startsAt.push(seat-adjacent)
    runLength.push(adjacent)
```

When this is done you have an array of all the blocks. Select only the blocks that are big enough (runLength() >= needed) and randomly choose one of them

Comment: I wanted this too initially, but my code has no way of knowing what a "row" is. Right now a row is just cut off through CSS, because the container is limiting the width (20 seats per row).